# How to expand (Square Wrap text) image in a two column document

Tags: floats, horizontal-alignment, wrap

I am writing a document using an `overleaf template` [IJMPI Template](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/ijmpi-template/dtxtmjfqgyqh).

I need to expand my images to more than 1 column but not necessary to expand the images for both columns. My expectation is the `Square or Tight Wrap text` feature of MS-Word. Similar kinds of [this](https://courses.lumenlearning.com/suny-wm-compapp/chapter/text-wrap/)

By default this template working only for one column.

I am writing this code to insert my images

```
\begin{figure}[!htb]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[scale=0.4]{Maximum Temperature.png}
    \caption{Maximum Temperature}
    \label{fig:test}
\end{figure}
```

Is there any way to expand my images like MS-Word square text wrap?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE... Please try with `\begin{figure*}....\end{figure*}`...

Comment: Thank you. Not working. Taking both columns. But I need to use suppose 1.5 columns and the rest of the 0.5 column will contain text.

Comment: The author guidelines of the `International Journal on Magnetic Particle Imaging` speaks only of one or two column pictures, not 1.5; so I'd rather contact the publisher on this...

Comment: Yes, I know. But, I was trying to add 1.5 columns for another purpose.